# Find the element one short of "closest"

Tags: jquery, closest

I want to add a class to the element that is the child of a known dom element which is one level below following the "path" that I went up the element tree. So in this case I want to target -- any-child-class***

I don't have control of any of the markup other than "start-here-class" and "closest-class". The includes not knowing the position of the target class within "closest-class" or the depth of "start-here-class" (so "counting" won't work in any respect for what I have in mind.

```
<div class="closest-class">
    <div class="any-child-class">
    <div class="any-child-class">
    <div class="any-child-class***">add a class to ONLY me!
        <div class="more-levels-class">
            <div class="more-levels-class">
                <div class="more-levels-class">
                    <div class="start-here-class">
    <div class="any-child-class">
    <div class="any-child-class">
```

JS:

`$(".start-here-class").closest(".closest-class")`

How do I get down one level?

Answer (score 0):

Find div using `eq` to add class with the help of `closest` .

```js
$(".start-here-class").closest(".closest-class").find("div").eq(3).addClass("customclass");
```

```css
.customclass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="closest-class">1
  <div class="any-child-class">1
    <div class="any-child-class">1
      <div class="any-child-class customclass">add a class to ONLY me!
        <div class="more-levels-class">
          <div class="more-levels-class">
            <div class="more-levels-class">
              <div class="start-here-class">
                <div class="any-child-class">
                  <div class="any-child-class">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use `class` to find div.

```js
$(".start-here-class").closest(".closest-class").find(".any-child-class1").addClass("customclass");
```

```css
.customclass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="closest-class">1
  <div class="any-child-class">1
    <div class="any-child-class">1
      <div class="any-child-class1">add a class to ONLY me!
        <div class="more-levels-class">
          <div class="more-levels-class">
            <div class="more-levels-class">
              <div class="start-here-class">
                <div class="any-child-class">
                  <div class="any-child-class">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't have control of any of the markup other than "start-here-class" and "closest-class". The includes not knowing the position of the target class within "closest-class" or the depth of "start-here-class" (so "counting" won't work in any respect for what I have in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In closest itself you can specify class name which you want to apply some style like below. `$(".start-here-class").closest(".closest-class .any-child-class-apply").css('color', 'red');`

```js
$(".start-here-class").closest(".closest-class .any-child-class-apply").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="closest-class">
    <div class="any-child-class">test
    <div class="any-child-class">test1
    <div class="any-child-class-apply">add a class to ONLY me!
        <div class="more-levels-class">
            <div class="more-levels-class">
                <div class="more-levels-class">
                    <div class="start-here-class">
                      <div class="any-child-class">
                        <div class="any-child-class">
                        </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: I don't have control of any of the markup other than "start-here-class" and "closest-class". The includes not knowing the position of the target class within "closest-class" or the depth of "start-here-class" (so "counting" won't work in any respect for what I have in mind.

Comment: what counting? In my answer didn't mentioned anywhere counting. Only parent and child representation is there in my answer.

Comment: thanks for your interest... I can't change the class to any-child-class-apply, the operation I need is occurring on load (not hover or scroll), if I could change the class I would simply do it in html.

Comment: you mean to say, you have a class name called exactly `any-child-class***` and you want to apply style fro this.

Comment: the aesthetics are for emphasis, generally what I'm saying is that I can't be sure what the specific markup will be. I know id will be surrounded by "closest-class" and it will contain "start-here-class". To give more context, The divs right below closest-class are rows and start-here-class is the nav and I want to target the row that contains nav without knowing what row the nav will be in.